# Which is the best approach to assign IP to amazon ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-web-services

I'am using Amazon SDK for PHP to create instances but I need to assign IP for each instance. In the case I create around 30 instances per week, which would be the best approach to assign IPs to them?

I see Elastic IP is the built-in solution for this, but I'am not sure if the limit can be extended to allow to create such amount of IPs.

I'am not sure if it's possible but if I have a range of IPs by my own, is there a way to assign them to the instances?

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign your own IP's to the instances. You have to use an elastic IP. You can get the limit removed by filling out this form:

http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/eip_limit_request/

However:

> **Note**: Elastic IPs are public (IPV4) internet addresses, and hence a scarce resource. We strongly encourage customers to use Elastic IPs
>   primarily for load balancing use cases, and private IP addresses for
>   all other internode communication. If you feel your architecture
>   warrants an exception, please continue to fill out the form below. We
>   appreciate you working with Amazon EC2 to use these public resources
>   efficiently.

So, why would you need so many Elastic Ip's? Set up a load balancer and use the internal IPs after that, it will end up costing you less.

Comment: Can you reference on some more information about setting a load balancer and assigning internal IPs after that?